# How to do category mapping from csv?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a csv form which I have to make the category mapping. I had let this csv read from controller.And, I am trying to establish a hierarchy .So, that I can map . But , I am not able to do that. Please help!
[link:https://pricefalls.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204287645-How-do-I-create-a-category-map- “Pricefalls Category Taxonomy”].My csv has the same pattern as shown in the given link.

```
 public function actionReadcsv()
    {
        $row = 1;
        $csvFile = Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . '/modules/pricefalls    /csv/Pricefalls_Categories1.csv';

        if (($handle = fopen($csvFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) {
                $row++;

                $create_category[] =$data;

            }
            Pricefallscategories::categorytree($create_category);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($create_category);
            echo"</pre>";
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "My csv has the same pattern as shown in the given link." 
I don't see  any link.
Plus - Personally I don't understand what you want to achieve, an example result array would be helpful.

Comment: https://pricefalls.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204287645-How-do-I-create-a-category-map-

Comment: I want to establish a parent-child(tree)/hierarchy through the the given csv.

Comment: ok, but what is the expected output format... as I said "an example result array would be helpful" - thing is, 'hierarchy' requires a tree structure, i.e. an array, with subarrays, with subarrays etc - but you named your result var '$csv', which doesn't make sense. So again - how should the expected output variable look like.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct sir . i want output in the same way as you said.

Comment: Sorry, I give up, you changed your code completely, now you introduced Pricefallscategories::categorytree which I have no idea what does it do and expects... I give up. I Hope some else will help.